# Mongodb checking and adding reference value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-query

I have two collections.

```
checkone
{"_id":1,"name":"alex"},
{"_id":2,"name":"sandy"}

checktwo
{"_id":11,"password":"alex",tenant_id:{$ref:"checkone","$id":1}}
{"_id":12,"password":"suman",tenant_id:{$ref:"checkone","$id":2}}
```

Checktwo tenant_id referencing the value of checkone id.

But when I try to insert another doc in checktwo

```
 {"_id":13,"password":"shan",tenant_id:{$ref:"checkone","$id":6}}
```

Its getting inserted. It doesnot checking whether the tenant_id value 6 exists in the checkone id value and adding it. In this condition, id value 6 doesnot exist in checkone but its getting inserted in checktwo tenant_id value.

Actually It must check and insert it right?

I have a confusion what does $ref mean here?

whether this functionality is not available in mongodb? Could anyone guide me if am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have made the classic mistake with MongoDB in thinking it has any relational abilities what-so-ever.

The DBRef is no relationship and it is not supported server side in any what-so-ever. It is not treated as an integral foreign key or a constraint by which to connect to other tables.

It is merely a driver side ability to have a self describing ID with a normalised way to lazily grab that other row out using a function like `getConnected()`.

The function of JOINs and constraints do not exist in MongoDB, you must manually on your side in your client code check for `6`s existance.

I suppoose you could argue that this behaviour should exist within the DBRef class and that, when set to a value not previously set, it should check for the existance of that other row. However at the moment it does not.

Comment: May I know the purpose of getConnected? Can you post me some links for it?

Comment: @Ruben It was just an example but here is the doc for Java: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBRef.html and the `getConnected()` function is actually `fetch` in your API I think.